# require Customizing UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a requirement where UIPickerView should be customised. The picker view should look adjacently  like this!

[https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1CHCBvB1IEebj82Xt1ZGBYTKhCUMBmeAeQBV5fvbI-6s/edit?usp=sharing

Any ideas on how to achieve this feat?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a picker view, you will break your head attempting to get it right.

Use a pair of ui table views, the left table cells correspond to right table sections. The right table sections are hidden until their respective, parallel row is selected

Sorry about formatting, on iPhone

Comment: can you give any example for same?